# Как передать переменнуюв функцию если я ее вызываю по клику на элементе страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, парсер

запускаю функцию так.

```js
$('#starter').click(parserGo);
```

Как получить переменную из вне внутри этой функции?

если сделать так.

```js
var Mask="Дымовой";
$('#starter').click(parserGo(Mask));
```

То что то происходит не верно. Запрос самопроизвольно запускается с самого начала и больше не работает.

Если из функции обратится к переменной напрямую то вместо того что написано внутри переменной console.log выдает это

Uncaught ReferenceError: Mask is not defined

Comment: Наверно можно удалить вопрос, дело было в том что внутри функции вызванной от jquery переменные локальные, поэтому наверно вызов из этой же функции обработчика клика не видел переменную прописанную в той же функции.

Comment: _Запрос самопроизвольно запускается с самого начала и больше не работает_ - ну так вы его и запускаете сразу. Передавайте функцию, а не выполняйте ее: `.click(function() { parserGo(Mask); } )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В jQuery когда мы вешаем любое событие на элемент практически очень редко нам приходиться дать параметры в функцию обработчик. Но в jQuery реализовано все это, оно называется [event.data](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/).
Вот простой пример где мы даем 2 параметра в функцию обработчик клика на элемент.

```js
$(".test_func").click({param1: "Hello", param2: "World"}, function(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
});

// in your function, just grab the event object and go crazy...
function cool_function(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test_func">test content</div>
```

Здесь функция обработчик написано отдельно, но мы можем и без разделения функции обработчика.

**Вот второй пример:**

```
$(".test_func").on('click',{param1: "Hello", param2: "World"},function(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
});
```

Comment: вместо написания двух _одинаковых_ ответов, стоило послать тревогу на дубликат

Comment: @Grundy хорошо в следующий раз если увижу обязательно сделаю так.